# How to get updated States at first time?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react states to store data that I am getting through axios from API. And I am changing some of the key values in my react states. those states are getting updated but not getting rendered those updated states.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            NewOrders:[],
        }
        this.getNewOrders();
    }
    getNewOrders = async () => {
        let data = await api.get(`SellerOrdersAPI/${store.getState().auth.user.id}/`).then(({data})=>data);
        data.map(a =>
            this.get(a)
            )
        console.log(this.state.NewOrders) 
        this.setState({NewOrders:data}) 
        this.testt()
    }
    get = async(a) => {
        let data1 = await itemApi.get(`/${a.item}/`).then(({data})=>data);
        a.item = data1.title
    }
```

here in console.log item value got updated but I can not render this newly updated value.
If I perform some operation on this component then this value (**22**) got changed by new value. but on start I can not access that.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Call `getNewOrders` in `componentDidMount` instead of `constructor`

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getNewOrders();
}
```

Comment: Sir I've tried it, But its giving same error